# How to add a comment style to an emacs mode

Tags: emacs, fortran, comments, elisp, syntax-highlighting

I am looking to add an additional single line style of comments !* to the Fortran mode on emacs, I'd add this to my init.el file.

From what I can see this should be doable using the `modify-syntax-entry` command, but I am struggling to succeed and there doesn't seem to be a `fortran-mode-syntax-table` so I can't see how I'd hook it to the mode.

My current effort (which causes an error).

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?\!\* "< \n")
(modify-syntax-entry ?\n "< \!\*")
```

The error reads *An error occurred while loading 'init.el': 
Invalid read syntax: ?*

Comment: If you have an error, you should show it.

Comment: However, I am surprised you need it. What is the suffix of your file? I recommend .f90 (or .F90 if it is preprocessed).

Comment: The error has been added, the preprocessing isn't the standard preprocessor, it is an additional preprocessor which is why I can't use .F90

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how to do this, and it's worth mentioning that with a normal Fortran setup ! causes comments, but not in mine.

So what I add to my init.el is

```
(add-hook 'fortran-mode-hook   
(lambda () 
(modify-syntax-entry ?\! ". 1")
(modify-syntax-entry ?\* ". 2")
(modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">") ))
```

The first two modify-syntax-entry use the numeric syntax flags for a two character comment start sequence !* and > is the syntax class for comment ended, for which I have used \n to end the comment with a newline.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Flags.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html#Syntax-Class-Table for more details